# ionic framework 3 help in css

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm a back end programmer, but I'm getting enough to fix the desing of my components, I wanted to improve my label / input, but I'm not able to ...

[image]

**HTML**

```
  <ion-item style="margin-left: -5%"> 
                    <ion-label style="font-size:15px;">Valor em BRL</ion-label>

                 <ion-input type="number"  [disabled]="!tempreco()"  [(ngModel)]="amount_from"   placeholder="00,00" ></ion-input>
            </ion-item> 

          <button ion-button small outline round   stacked style=" margin-left: 20%;" (click)="usarSaldo()">Usar saldo</button>
             <ion-item style="margin-left: -5%"> 
                  <ion-label style="font-size:15px;">Valor em BTC</ion-label>

                 <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price"   placeholder="00,00" ></ion-input>

            </ion-item> 
                <ion-item>
              <ion-select [(ngModel)]="option" value="limitado">
                <ion-option value="MERC">Mercado</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="LMTD">Limitado</ion-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: let the beautiful input / label put something around, or underline it ...

Comment: Please update with your question so that we can help you.

Take a stackoverflow tour to get to know more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/tour